# Why does findIndex() return 0, instead of the desired index?

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck trying to figure out how to retrieve a desired index. I have a user adding names to a Guestlist, with the option to remove names. All the names are appended to an array saved to localStorage. When the delete button is clicked, I want to iterate over the array, find the matching string and retrieve it's index. All I'm getting however, is a -1 if the string doesn't match, and 0 if it matches. Where is my error? Any help is appreciated.

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {     // Makes the Delete button active.
            const deleteName = this.parentElement.innerText;     // parent element is li
            const test = localStorage.getItem('data');
            const testParsed = JSON.parse(test);
           
            for (let i = 0; i < testParsed.length; i++) {
                let compare = `Name: ${testParsed[i].name}, About: ${testParsed[i].about}Delete entry`; // matches innerHtml of deleteName
               compare.replace('.,:', '');    // Removes unwanted punctuation
                console.log('Compare: ', compare);

                function index(){
                    return deleteName === compare;
                }
                console.log(testParsed.findIndex(index));
```

Comment: Side note: `compare.replace()` does *not* modify the contents of `compare`. And the index() function needs a parameter: `function index(deleteName){ ... }` (or to avoid confusion, maybe use a different name because `deleteName` is already being used)

Comment: Like so?
 `
 function index(equals){
                    return equals === compare;
                }
                console.log(testParsed.findIndex(index));
`

Comment: Yes, or something else, personally I would use a name like `item`, `entry` or `text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around some more, and figured it out. I'll leave the question up in case someone else can make use of it.

```
     deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {  // Makes the Delete button active.
            const deleteName = this.parentElement.innerText; // parent element is li
            const test = localStorage.getItem('data');
            const testParsed = JSON.parse(test);
            console.log(test);

            for (let i = 0; i < testParsed.length; i++) {
                let compare = `Name: ${testParsed[i].name}, About: ${testParsed[i].about}Delete entry`; // matches innerHtml of deleteName
               compare.replace('.,:', '');  // Removes unwanted punctuation
                console.log('Compare: ', compare);


                if(deleteName === compare) {
                    function index(equals) {  // compare is string, equals is object
                        return equals.name === testParsed[i].name && equals.about === testParsed[i].about;
                    }

                    console.log(testParsed.findIndex(index));
                }
```